# What are the attributes of a good repertoire request?

Tags: discussion

I voted to close this question on the basis of its being too broad:

[Piano Piece Recommendations](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82625/piano-piece-recommendations)

My reasons for voting to close were that the two works mentioned by the OP as an indication of present level were quite insufficient to estimate that level in and of themselves, and that no qualified evaluation of their performance was mentioned.

However, I voted with some misgivings. I find such questions interesting, if well posed. In principle, they can be of value to other readers. I would appreciate some advice from the community on how to judge acceptable repertoire requests. What are the attributes of a good one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [help center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the following is off-topic:

> - recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet particular criteria

It seems to me that repertoire requests would fall into that category.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to ask a question like the linked example in such a way that users in a similar position could easily find the question, and in such a way that opinion-based answers would be minimized. For example, we can recommend one work that leads to another based on specific technical grounds. This can be done fairly objectively. However, my efforts to invent an example question that would satisfy these demands failed, so I now understand why this policy is in place.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible (but be careful) to get around that requirement, specifically by asking why certain songs achieve the thing you want in your repertiore and asking for other examples. It's going to be debated either way, so I wouldn't hold my breath.